# Wrapper function in R

Tags: r, wrapper

Can anyone help me understand what a wrapper function in r is? I would really appreciate if you could explain it with the help of examples on building one's own wrapper function and when to use one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really an R-specific question.  As the name implies, a wrapper function is just a function which wraps another function.  Maybe inside it does something like set some default values for parameters, etc.

Comment: Or it can be a way of having two names for the same thing.  Type `dir` at the console, and you will see it is just a wrapper for `list.files`, for example.

Comment: Like Tim said, it's not supposed to be a wholly new concept, it's just a modification to an existing function. For example, I wrote a wrapper for the merge function to display some additional text output like the number of matched and unmatched entries from both sides. It still calls merge and takes all of merge's arguments, it just gives some additional output.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Say I want to use `mean()` but I want to set some default arguments and my usecase doesn't allow me to add additional arguments when I'm actually calling `mean()`.

I could create a wrapper function:

```
mean_noNA <- function(x) {
    return(mean(x, na.rm = T))
}
```

`mean_noNA` is a wrapper for `mean()` where we have set `na.rm` to TRUE.

Now we could use `mean_noNA(x)` the same as `mean(x, na.rm = T)`.

Comment: That was a great example of a wrapper in R, for people who starts digging deeper in this programming language. Now, I'm going to investigate more on bindings.

Answer (score 4):

[Wrapper functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function) occur in any programming language, and they just mean that you are "wrapping" one function inside another function that alters how it works in some useful way.  When we refer to a "wrapper" function we mean a function that the main purpose of the function is to call some internal function; there may be some alteration or additional computation in the wrapper, but this is sufficiently minor that the original function constitutes the bulk of the computation.

As an example, consider the following wrapper function for the `log` function in `R`.  One of the drawbacks of the original function is that it does not work properly for negative numeric inputs (it gives `NaN` with a warning message).  We can remedy this by creating a "wrapper" function that turns it into the [complex logarithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64257736/):

```
Log <- function(x, base = exp(1)) {
  LOG <- base::log(as.complex(x), base = base)
  if (all(Im(LOG) == 0)) { LOG <- Re(LOG) }
  LOG }
```

The function `Log` is a "wrapper" for `log` that adjusts it so that it will now accept numeric or complex inputs, including negative numeric inputs.  In the event that it receives a non-negative numeric or a complex input it gives the same output the original `log` function.  However, if it is given a negative numeric input it gives the complex output that should be returned by the complex logarithm.